# Fastest way to scrape followers from a Twitter account with Node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter, scrape

Due to the limit rate of twitter API I would like to know how could I scrape **the number of followers** from a Twitter account with Node.js in a very **very fast way**?
Do you think Node.js is the best solution to do it?

I have no idea of how it works but I thought that perhaps scraping to the Twitter mobile version ( example https://mobile.twitter.com/android)  would be faster than the computer version.

What do you think? How could I do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the Twitter v1.0 API has been deprecated, you must use oauth signed requests.
Which means Twitter knows when you abuse the system.

Docs on oath signed requests:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth

Docs on rate limiting:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

Rate limiting applies to the API, not unauthenticated http requests which simply scrape the content.

If you just want the follower count and not the individual follower ids / details, you can simply scrape the page using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) and use [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) to filter down the results using selectors.

eg.
https://twitter.com/foofighters

You can run this client side to preview the results:

```
$('.js-mini-profile-stats a.js-nav[data-nav=followers] strong').attr('title')
```

Comment: "The fastest way"? Unless you have a ton of servers with high speed bandwidth, you'd benefit from using an external scraping service such as http://80legs.com/

Comment: here is a script which uses casperjs and phantomjs and its fast.

https://gist.github.com/maxpaynestory/02563716bef271316c3d